# Momentum variance in momentum space for particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration

My assignment asks me to compute the momentum space wavefunction of the nth energy eigenstate of the particle in a one-dimensional infinite square well, then "show that your result is in agreement with the uncertainty principle".

The momentum space wavefunction I obtained is:

$$\phi(p) = n\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\hbar L^3}} \frac{p^2}{p^2-(n\pi\hbar/L)^2}(1-(-1)^n e^{-ipL/\hbar})$$

with corresponding probability density

$$|\phi(p)|^2 = \frac{2\pi n^2}{\hbar L^3} \left(\frac{p^2}{p^2 - (n\pi \hbar/L)^2}\right)^2 \left(1-(-1)^n \cos \frac{L}{\hbar}p\right)$$

Since this is odd, it's obvious that $\langle p \rangle = 0$. However, I can't figure out how to do the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p^2 |\phi(p)|^2 \, dp$ to obtain $\langle p^2 \rangle$, even though I could easily compute $\langle p^2 \rangle$ using the position-space wavefunction. I also couldn't get Mathematica to do it. Should I just tell my prof it couldn't be done the way he wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Stay in position space, with the $\phi(x)$, because the calculus is much simpler, because the  $\phi(x)$ are $\sin$ functions, see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Wavefunctions).

Remember that, in position space, we have : $\hat P= - i \hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $\hat P^2 = - \hbar^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$

So, if $\phi_n(x)$ is your normalized wave function, in your infinite square well between $x=a$ and $x=b$, you have :

$$\langle\hat P\rangle_n = \int_a^b \phi_n^*(x) \left(- i \hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right) \phi_n(x)$$

$$\langle\hat P^2\rangle_n = \int_a^b \phi_n^*(x) \left(- \hbar^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\right) \phi_n(x)$$

Comment: With these guidelines, try to find the solution by yourself, then compare to the [solution](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/PrtinboxHeisenbergn.pdf)